# encode video into three different formats using ffmpeg on one button click

Tags: ffmpeg

I am facing problem in converting/encoding any video into three formats i-e; webm, mp4 and flv on video upload at one button click. But the problem is some videos are converting and some or not. Example when i am trying to convert mp4 to flv some mp4 videos are converting and some are not. i am using this command to convert it. i tried other commands too but this one is working for few mp4 files other one are not working for any file. Here is the command

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c:v libx264 -crf 28 output.flv
```

which is exactly like this i put with php code

```
passthru("ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c:v libx264 -crf 28 output.flv")
```

I am also facing issues with converting avi and ogg files to mp4, webm and flv. its really strange. Please help.

Thanks

Comment: How some videos convert and someone not ? May be it differs with formats or some size ??

Comment: i am just using mp4 format. and some files which are converting successfully are larger than the files which are not converting.

Comment: Ah, I am sure that `ffmpeg` will take more time to convert.. So, Have you adjusted the maximum execution time accordingly ?

Comment: I would recommend to use cron job for this purpose.. Where user will upload the video and it will be converted in the background. So the user don't want to wait untill the video converts ;)

Comment: i set execution time to 3000 and input time to 3000. will cron jobs work?

Comment: I just tried a video of 24 mb and and it got converted successfully. and then i convert 9mb file it didnt convert. isnt it strange?

Comment: You can't say the `3000` or some values in php.ini just set `set_time_limit(0);` to set unlimited time

Comment: and what should i set max_execution_time?

Comment: There might be some other reasons. such as file permsission or path or video extension such as .mp4 or .MP4

Comment: It means unlmited time `set_time_limit(0);`

Comment: Yes cron job will do definitely

Comment: ok then i should try set time limit and cron jobs. I hope it will work in my case too

Comment: Yes.. Cron job is nothing but it will runs in the background in particular interval of time..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79654/discussion-between-sulthan-allaudeen-and-aisha).

Answer (score 0):

you have not specified acodec parameter

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -acodec libvo_aacenc -vcodec libx264 -crf 28 output.flv
```

Even if, this doesn't help check for the error, it will always give you the clue what to add.